# Цветы-двулетники или цветы двулетники?

Tags: приложение

Цветы-двулетники или цветы двулетники? Стоит ли ставить дефис?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь приложение, а по общему правилу оно требует постановки дефиса.

Comment: *двулетник — это всегда цветок* — с ботаникой у Вас не очень :) Морковь и капусту, например, Вы тоже считаете цветочками?

Comment: Ну да, отредактировал. Спасибо